# how to get https request as raw data before encryption

Tags: firefox, https, sniffing

I need to get https request as raw data before encryption. I can't use wireshark because it shows me encrypted data and I havn't rsa private key. I just want to connect to the remote https server and to sniff conversation between https server and me without encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the observer service notifications listed here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests

like `http-on-opening-request` or `http-on-modify-request`